# react create dynamic tree recursively

Tags: recursion, reactjs, tree

thanks for reading and helping. Here is my situation so far:

1. I have much data in database, each piece of data has id, parentid(which means you can find the id of its parent using this parentid ), name, description.
2. I want to create a dynamic tree using react,but I do not know how many levels of nodes I have.  Each node represents for an id in database.  An user clicks on a node A on this tree, the children nodes whose parentid equals to A's id will show/hide.
3. I do not intend to retrieve all the data because it will take long time. Now I am able to get one node's children by sending request and get response.body:

   ```
    getChildren(id){
       ajax.get('http://localhost:8080/configmgmt/code/category/retriveTree/' + id)
      .end((error, response) => {
      if (!error && response) {
      console.dir(response.body );
      this.setState(subdata:response.body});

   } else {
      console.log('There was an error fetching from database', error);
       }
      }
    );
   }
   ```
4. in render part, I wrote:

   ```
      {this.state.subdata.map((rb,index)=>{
               return  <li><div><a href='##' onClick = {this.getChildren.bind(this,rb.id)}><em></em><label className="one_title">{rb.name}</label></a></div></li>})
       }
   ```

Here comes the question, I still do not know how to create the tree recursively(because any node might has its children nodes ). how to do this when we can only get a node's children nodes from the database?

Answer (score 1):

I would do your task in two steps:

- Create a structure for an augmented tree with loading status flags. It should have a structure like this (this is pseudocode):

  ```
  class Node {
     loaded: boolean,
     expanded: boolean,
     children: list<Node>
  }
  ```
- Create a component for this:

  - If node isn't expanded don't render its children
  - If use clicks on expand sign
  - If children are loaded, do nothing, just change the expanded field
  - If children aren't loaded

    - set expanded to true
    - initiate ajax request
    - as soon as the request completes, set loaded to true, and assign children

Creating a component which recursively uses itself isn't a problem. If you don't know how to do this read here: [how to render child components in react.js recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28205317/how-to-render-child-components-in-react-js-recursively)