# in react why my console says, "Failed to construct 'Comment'?

Tags: reactjs

error looks like this -

**Failed to construct 'Comment': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function**

don't understand how to use "new" operator and what does it mean! can anyone please help me?

here is the code -

```
import React from "react";
import {render} from "react-dom";



class Board extends React.Component{
  state ={comments: ["I like bla", "what next?", "this is the last."]}

  eachComment(text, i){
    return (<Comment key={i}>{text}</Comment>);
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        {
          this.state.comments.map(this.eachComment)
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<Board/>, window.document.getElementById("example"));
```

Answer (score 0):

should be

```
constructor() {
this.state ={comments: ["I like bla", "what next?", "this is the last."]}
}
```

instead of `state ={comments: ["I like bla", "what next?", "this is the last."]}`

Answer (score 0):

Inside a class for state it should be `this.state =` this is so that the class holds the data and react component is looking for the state on the class

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with these changes ?

```
class Board extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
     super();
     this.state ={comments: ["I like bla", "what next?", "this is the last."]};
  }
...
}
```

and specify `eachComment` as an object above `render()`

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28205521/3279391