# Render React component in nested list

Tags: reactjs, recursion, react-redux, jsx, nested-sets

If we write something like below in ItemsList component:

```jsx
    render(){ 
       return(
          <div>
             <ul>
                {this.props.items.map(item => <Item key={item.id} />)}
             </ul>
          </div>
   )
```

Output should be something like:

```jsx
<div>
         <ul>
              <li></li>
              <li></li>
              <li></li>
              <li></li>
              <li></li>
          </ul>
</div>
```

And it is clear that in Item component render method is like

```jsx
render(){
        return(
            <li>
                **smth here***
            </li>
        )
    }
```

Is there a way to render that kind of components with output like:

```jsx
 <ul>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

What I mean: we got array, take first item scan it, then we take another item and after scanning note that they are should stay near with previous item (for example), and now we have structure ul>li*2, then, after further scanning there no siblings, so we take another item and make same scanning, in the end we renders the structure like above.

Yes, scanning should recursively run through array and check some props.
Below the function which do what I need (logically), and even show nested list. The main problem is how to **render react components that way**

```jsx
 renderItems(items) {
    //find where to render
    let node = document.getElementById('root');
    node.innerHTML = '';
    if (items.length) {
        var ul = document.createElement('ul');
        var tree = fetchChildElement(ul);
        node.appendChild(tree);
    }
    function fetchChildElement(container, lft, rgt) {
        items.filter(filterItems); //go through data array 
        return container;

        function filterItems(item) {
            //check if item exists in array 
            if (item.Lft === (lft || 0)) {
                var element = document.createElement('li');
                element.innerHTML = (item.Lft + " | " + item.Rgt);

               //check if item got nested items
                if (item.Lft + 1 < item.Rgt) {
                   //if true call recursive function
                   var childContainer = document.createElement('ul');
                   var child = fetchChildElement(childContainer, item.Lft + 1, item.Rgt - 1);
                   element.appendChild(child);
                }

                //add item to array
                container.appendChild(element);

                //check if next element exists and call function for them
                if (rgt && item.Rgt < rgt) {
                   //if true call recursive function
                   fetchChildElement(container, item.Rgt + 1, rgt);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The main idea that I can't understand (and can't find) is:

- Is there a way to render several `<li>` react components in different `<ul>`s?
- Using simple javascript with its appendChild - there is no problems, may be there are alternative in React?
- Also, maybe it would be necessary, I am using react-redux, and data comes from server, and correct render should be in my frontend.

Any tips or advices?

**EDIT**

My state of items looks like following
[image]

**EDIT**
This is output of my js function, which take Items array and show only leftKey|rightKey (lets say it is img1):
[image]

That is output of Items (just map through Item array to render each Item), display:inline-block just to easy looking (lets say it is img2):
[image]

And the final output should be elements like on img2, but hierarchically like on the img1.

And below the schema how it should like (left side) and for better understanding the same in a tree view (right side)

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to render child components in react.js recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28205317/how-to-render-child-components-in-react-js-recursively)

Comment: what does the state look like that you are trying to render also?

Comment: @canaanseaton Img with state added. It is array of objects..

Comment: @DanO Google got a lot of example how to render recursively, but all of them is when there are nested "children", but as far as I understand it is not my case.

Comment: It would appear so, I am having a hard time determining why you need to recurse in the first place. Perhaps I am not understanding what you want to be rendered.  Can you post what the output should look like say for the first two elements in the sample state that you posted for clarification?

Comment: @canaanseaton Edit my answer, thought it should be a little bit clearly what I want in final. If it would be still bad for understanding - I will try to Paint.

Comment: hmm what conditions cause the list to nest/recurse?

Comment: @canaanseaton conditions are in js function renderItems(items). It takes the array and check left and right keys of Item to realize is it nested or has nested items. The 5th code fragment is this function itself with comments what every check do. For testing i do  ` return (<div>  {this.renderItems(items)} </div>   ) ` and it nest items` left and right keys like on img1 (but the same should be with elements like on img2). But I can`t understand how to do smth similar to appendChild and createElement like I do in that function, to render my Item components

Comment: @canaanseaton For better viewlization added Paintmade output which is needed (left side of image)

Comment: I apologize but I do not see how your output is rendered from the set of sample functions you listed.  Best of luck in resolving your answer.  But just so you know, anything that can be done in vanilla js can be done via `React-ive` syntax.