# React recursion with map does not work for the nested elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recursion

I am new to react, I have tried to create a nested tree of folders and files of recursion. I have created 03 components Tree, Folder, and File. In the tree I have put the logic of recursion I map all the elements if I find a folder I create the folder and recall the function if I find a file I display it directly (see code below).

The function creates the level 0 elements only. I wonder why once I recall again the function Tree `<Tree tree ={item.items}/>` inside the folder it does function. Any hint?

```js
export function Tree ({tree})  {
const items = tree
  return (
   <>
    {items.map((item, idx) => { 
            if (item.items) {
                /**
                 * is Folder
                 */
                return (
                    <Folder key={idx} folder_name={item.name} num_folders={items.length} >
                        {<Tree tree ={item.items}/> /**this does not work**/}
                    </Folder>
                )
            }
            else {
                return (
                <File key={idx} file_name= {item.name} file_icon={item.icon} file_size ={item.size} />
                ) 
            }
        })}
   </>
  );
}
```

Comment: check if this is helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28205317/how-to-render-child-components-in-react-js-recursively

Comment: I have tried to create them within a function that I will call in the render method but does not work too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use React `children` property.

> children is a special property of React components which contains any child elements defined within the component, e.g. the divs inside Example above. {this.props.children} includes those children in the rendered result.

So what u insert inside the `<Folder> </Folder>` will be rendered via `children` property. Just update your folder components to render those children items like this:

```
export function Folder({ other_props, children}){
    ...
    return (
        <div>
            ... 
            {
                children 
            }    
        </div>
    );
}
```

Read more about `children` property in this stack question [What is {this.props.children} and when you should use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49706823/what-is-this-props-children-and-when-you-should-use-it)